# Finding cyclic single transposition vector in C

Tags: c, algorithm

I have the input as array `A = [ 2,3,4,1]`

The output is simply all possible permutation from elements in A which can be done by single transposition (single flip of two neighbouring elements) operation. So the output is :

```
[3,2,4,1],[ 2,4,3,1],[2,3,1,4],[1,3,4,2]
```

Circular transpositioning is allowed. Hence `[2,3,4,1]` ==> `[1,3,4,2]` is allowed and a valid output.

How to do it in C?

**EDIT**
In python, it would be done as follows:

```
def Transpose(alist):
    leveloutput = []
    n = len(alist)
    for i in range(n):
        x=alist[:]
        x[i],x[(i+1)%n] = x[(i+1)%n],x[i]
        leveloutput.append(x)
    return leveloutput
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it without C, in another language? Show me please...

Comment: @Technopolice Does it have to be C? If you pick C++, you will have better library support for dynamic structures allowing you to almost do a line-by-line translation. Although in this case, since you know that size of `leveloutput` beforehand, it isn't as big a difference.

Comment: In C it is preferred because of performance. Testing some new algorithm and part of which is this function. It has to perform better when the test matrix is very large, hence chosen is C :(

Comment: "Preferring" C over C++ because of "performance" shows the person who made this decision knows very little about 3 things: C, C++ and performance.

Comment: @Agent_L Unfortunately that person is me :) Started with python. I could do things. But next step is come up with C as to include it as headers.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses dynamic memory allocation, this way you can do it for an array of size `size`.

```
int *swapvalues(const int *const array, size_t size, int left, int right)
{
    int *output;
    int  sotred;

    output = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (output == NULL) /* check for success */
        return NULL;
    /* copy the original values into the new array */
    memcpy(output, array, size * sizeof(int));
    /* swap the requested values */
    sotred        = output[left];
    output[left]  = output[right];
    output[right] = sotred;

    return output;
}

int **transpose(const int *const array, size_t size)
{
    int **output;
    int   i;
    int   j;

    /* generate a swapped copy of the array. */
    output = malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
    if (output == NULL) /* check success */
        return NULL;
    j = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < size - 1 ; ++i)
    {
        /* allocate space for `size` ints */
        output[i] = swapvalues(array, size, j, 1 + j);
        if (output[i] == NULL)
            goto cleanup;
        /* in the next iteration swap the next two values */
        j += 1;
    }
    /* do the same to the first and last element now */
    output[i] = swapvalues(array, size, 0, size - 1);
    if (output[i] == NULL)
        goto cleanup;
    return output;

cleanup: /* some malloc call returned NULL, clean up and exit. */
    if (output == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (j = i ; j >= 0 ; j--)
        free(output[j]);
    free(output);

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    int array[4] = {2, 3, 4, 1};
    int i;
    int **permutations = transpose(array, sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));
    if (permutations != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0 ; i < 4 ; ++i)
        {
            int j;

            fprintf(stderr, "[ ");
            for (j = 0 ; j < 4 ; ++j)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "%d ", permutations[i][j]);
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "] ");
            free(permutations[i]);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    }
    free(permutations);

    return 0;
}
```

Although some people think `goto` is evil, this is a very nice use for it, don't use it to control the flow of your program (for instance to create a loop), that is confusing. But for the exit point of a function that has to do several things before returning, it think it's actually a nice use, it's my opinion, for me it makes the code easier to understand, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this code I have written with an example :

```
void transpose() {
    int arr[] = {3, 5, 8, 1};
    int l = sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr[0]);
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        j = (i + 1) % l;
        int copy[l];
        for (k = 0; k < l; k++)
            copy[k] = arr[k];
        int t = copy[i];
        copy[i] = copy[j];
        copy[j] = t;
        printf("{%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", copy[0], copy[1], copy[2], copy[3]);
    }
}
```

**Sample Output :**

```
{5, 3, 8, 1}
{3, 8, 5, 1}
{3, 5, 1, 8}
{1, 5, 8, 3}
```

Comment: Cool. But cant we make the above function to return the array of arrays? Like {{5, 3, 8, 1},{3, 8, 5, 1},{3, 5, 1, 8},{1, 5, 8, 3}}

Comment: Something like I pass an array to the function and it returns the array of arrays ?  I tried, but many errors :(

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

- a single memory block is preferred to, say, an array of pointers because of better locality and less heap fragmentation;
- the cyclic transposition is only one, it can be done separately, thus avoiding the overhead of the modulo operator in each iteration.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int *single_transposition(const int *a, unsigned int n) {
  // Output size is known, can use a single allocation
  int *out = malloc(n * n * sizeof(int));

  // Perform the non-cyclic transpositions
  int *dst = out;
  for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    memcpy(dst, a, n * sizeof (int));
    int t = dst[i];
    dst[i] = dst[i + 1];
    dst[i + 1] = t;
    dst += n;
  }

  // Perform the cyclic transposition, no need to impose the overhead
  // of the modulo operation in each of the above iterations.
  memcpy(dst, a, n * sizeof (int));
  int t = dst[0];
  dst[0] = dst[n-1];
  dst[n-1] = t;

  return out;
}

int main() {include 
  int a[] = { 2, 3, 4, 1 };
  const unsigned int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
  int *b = single_transposition(a, n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n * n; ++i)
    printf("%d%c", b[i], (i % n) == n - 1 ? '\n' : ' ');
  free(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle this problem, and most important questions are: how you're going to consume the output and how variable is the size of the array. You've already said the array is going to be very large, therefore I assume memory, not CPU will be the biggest bottleneck here.

If output is going to be used only few times (especially just once), it'll may be best to use functional approach: generate every transposition on the fly, and never have more than one in memory at a time. For this approach many high level languages would work as well as (maybe sometimes even better than) C.

If size of the array is fixed, or semi-fixed (eg few sizes known at compile-time), you can define structures, using C++ templates at best.

If size is dynamic and you still want to have every transposition in memory then you should allocate one huge memory block and treat it as contiguous array of arrays. This is very simple and straightforward on machine level. Unfortunately it's best tackled using pointer arithmetic, one feature of C/C++ that is renowned for being difficult to understand. (It isn't if you learn C from basics, but people jumping down from high level languages have proven track record of getting it completely wrong first time)
Other approach is to have big array of pointers to smaller arrays, which results in double pointer, the ** which is even more terrifying to newcomers.

Sorry for long post which is not a real answer, but IMHO there are too many questions left open for choosing the best solution and I feel you need bit more C basic knowledge to manage them on your own.

/edit:
As other solutions are already posted, here's a solution with minimum memory footprint. This is the most limiting approach, it uses same one buffer over and over, and you must be sure that your code is finished with first transposition before moving on to the next one. On the bright side, it'll still work just fine when other solutions would require terabyte of memory. It's also so undemanding that it might be as well implemented with a high level language. I insisted on using C++ in case you would like to have more than one matrix at a time (eg comparing them OR running several threads concurrently).

```
#define NO_TRANSPOSITION -1

class Transposable1dMatrix
{
    private:
    int * m_pMatrix;
    int m_iMatrixSize;
    int m_iCurrTransposition;
    //transposition N means that elements N and N+1 are swapped
    //transpostion -1 means no transposition
    //transposition (size-1) means cyclic transpostion
    //as usual in C (size-1) is the last valid index

public:
    Transposable1dMatrix(int MatrixSize)
    {
        m_iMatrixSize = MatrixSize;
        m_pMatrix = new int[m_iMatrixSize];
        m_iCurrTransposition = NO_TRANSPOSITION;
    }

    int* GetCurrentMatrix()
    {
        return m_pMatrix;
    }

    bool IsTransposed()
    {
        return m_iCurrTransposition != NO_TRANSPOSITION;
    }

    void ReturnToOriginal()
    {
        if(!IsTransposed())//already in original state, nothing to do here
            return;
        //apply same transpostion again to go back to original
        TransposeInternal(m_iCurrTransposition);
        m_iCurrTransposition = NO_TRANSPOSITION;
    }

    void TransposeTo(int TranspositionIndex)
    {
        if(IsTransposed())
            ReturnToOriginal();
        TransposeInternal(TranspositionIndex);
        m_iCurrTransposition = TranspositionIndex;
    }

private:
    void TransposeInternal(int TranspositionIndex)
    {
        int Swap1 = TranspositionIndex;
        int Swap2 = TranspositionIndex+1;
        if(Swap2 == m_iMatrixSize)
            Swap2 = 0;//this is the cyclic one
        int tmp = m_pMatrix[Swap1];
        m_pMatrix[Swap1] = m_pMatrix[Swap2];
        m_pMatrix[Swap2] = tmp;
    }
};

void main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 1};
    int size = 4;
    //allocate
    Transposable1dMatrix* test = new Transposable1dMatrix(size);
    //fill data
    memcpy(test->GetCurrentMatrix(), arr, size * sizeof (int));
    //run test
    for(int x = 0; x<size;x++)
    {
        test->TransposeTo(x);
        int* copy = test->GetCurrentMatrix();
        printf("{%d, %d, %d, %d}\n", copy[0], copy[1], copy[2], copy[3]);
    }
}
```